# How to run a service of installed app in devices programatically

Tags: android, android-service

I have a function to get running services:

```
public ArrayList<String> getRunningServices() {

    ActivityManager activityMg = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> serviceList = activityMg.getRunningServices(100);
    ArrayList<String> serviceName = new ArrayList<String>();

 for (int i=0; i<serviceList.size(); i++) {
       ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo currentService = serviceList.get(i);
       boolean serviceNam = currentService.started;
       if (serviceNam == true) {
           serviceName.add(currentService.service.getPackageName());
    }

     }

    return serviceName;

}
```

Now I want to run one of these services if it is stopped.

To run an installed app I have to use intent like this code:

```
      Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(nameOfPakage);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

But I want to just run a service of this app or another one.

I have a String name of package of app and i want start its service.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there below is to start a service from another application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String pkg = currentService.service.getPackageName();
String cls = currentService.service.getPackageName() + "." + currentService.service.getClassName();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
startService(intent);
```

Comment: thanks Kevin but it's not correct because in the "currentService " we have running services and we don't know which one is not running. you said that "Service not running..." but in "else" the service is running and it's not  explicitly started. it's in background.

Comment: Sorry I am replying with slight of hand the code provided was intended to help withe the question of starting a service that is not part of your app, let me edited my answer :)

Comment: getRunningServices will return only running services maybe need to find a way to get stopped services

Comment: Got a thought on it give me a few :)

Comment: thanks... i edit my question :) my function have a string name parameter that is name of package name of app we want run its service

Comment: The only way I can think of now, is store information about service in a table and periodically query the table against the getRunningServices and start them with the way I showed you above :) remember to keep it consistent don't add duplicates to table and insert new services if it wasnt in table, or update if already in table

Comment: Ok... tanks a lot Kevin... :)

Comment: No problem If i find another way I will keep updated :)